# A third party site stole my SO post and is pretending I'm a contributing author to their site

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

**(I have read the tag wiki for [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites). However, this site *does* include attribution, but does so in a misleading way that is faking direct affiliation with myself.)**

A website masquerading as a "tech blog", but whose content is entirely ripped from other sites, has stolen a particularly dumb SO question of mine and pasted it word-for-word as a blog post on their site. My full name is listed as the Author.

Although I don't really mind my question being shared, it's being shared in a context where it is clearly meant to look like I'm a personal, affiliated contributor to that website's blog. There is attribution in the form of a single stackoverflow link, but this is tucked away at the bottom in a way that feels deliberately designed to make sure you don't notice it. My full name, however, is put in big block letters beneath the "article", where it tells users they can "Read more posts by this author."

(Ironically, the site has also stolen an article on how to avoid getting your articles stolen!)

Is content on SO licensed in such a way that this is legally acceptable, i.e. does the principle that code provided in answers is acceptable for personal project (re)use also extend to the text content of questions and answers? Or would I be fine to seek some recourse (i.e. a takedown notice) over this?

**Edit:**

The article in question also fails to link to my author page, hence failing the Attribution requirement. I will put in a notice and may also inform cloudflare of the site's persistent copyright infringement of thousands of articles.

Looking at this situation, however, in the future it may be valuable to also require that sites don't *overstate* attribution by faking affiliation, as well.

Comment: Does it follow all 4 attribution requirements?: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/, if not, then it does _not_ include attribution

Comment: You should read the license under which you've shared *all* of your content posted on this site (not just code). There's a link to it in the lower right of every page. Note: nothing has been stolen.

Comment: @Nick upon reviewing that article, and checking back on the website, it looks like it fails to link to my profile page - although I feel that another attribution clause of "doesn't pretend the SO user in question is affiliated with their website" would be a valuable requirement to have!

Comment: @Nick The blog post you've linked to appears to be something of a mashup of what's required by the CC BY-SA license and what Stack Exchange required in their Terms of Service at the time of the blog (based on my memory of earlier TOS versions, but not actually checking in detail). The ToS issues are between SO/SE and the blog company. The requirements under the CC BY-SA license are what the copyright holder (the OP) can require compliance with. I detail my understanding of those requirements in [my answer here](/a/356304/3773011). It's for a slightly different situation, but is applicable.

Comment: @EthanMcTague I'd note that the CC BY-SA license gives you the right to require that your name be removed from copies which are republished (i.e. what the blog company is doing). See the end of CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(a). IIRC, it's substantially similar for CC BY-SA 4.0, but may be in a different section number. In other words, you can require that they remove your name from the blog entry. Note: IANAL: if you have actual legal questions, consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Makyen That's pretty valuable information - I hadn't looked *that* in-depth. I have submitted a general request with Cloudflare for the site on the grounds that its entire purpose is to steal literally thousands of other author's works (incl. plenty of evidence of others complaining) so something may be done about it regardless of copyright.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, I read the question from the point of view of how it would be dealt with by SO for being in breach of their terms and would would constitute breaching those terms (*"does the principle that code provided in answers is acceptable for personal project (re)use also extend to the text content of questions and answers?"* - Yes, yes it does, _with_ proper attribution) but like you... IANAL :p

Comment: Name and shame.

Comment: Can you provide a link?  It's easier to come to a conclusion based on the page rather than a description of the page.

Comment: @Nick, does this apply to (business) source code too? I usually just put a (direct) link toward the answer in a comment when I reuse specific answer snippets.

Comment: @Amessihel IANAL, I am not a lawyer, consult your employer and their legal team

Comment: @Nick, no, I mean from the point of view of SO.

Comment: @Amessihel Consult _their_ legal team? :p I am in no way am expert on the topic

Comment: @Nick, ok time to post a new SO META question then...

Comment: @Nick, you were pretty peremptory in your comment though. :D

Comment: @Amessihel Just slightly busy :) and want to make sure nobody does anything based on the words of some guy on the Internet

Comment: @EthanMcTague, in the absence of a link there is the danger that people may start to assume you are overstating what the site is doing.  Please do supply a link so that doubters can be assured this is not the case.

Comment: Is it [this one](https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/59858617.html)? It is a copy of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660713/including-header-file-from-static-library). I don't see the link to the SO over there, though.

Comment: The license of the content here is pretty liberal and allows others to share and modify the content under certain circumstances. In principle all contributors here can become contributors to the same or modified content on other sites too. Therefore it could actually be true, you could be an contributing author (in a way).

Comment: Downvoted because no link to the allegedly offending content. For f\*\*k's sake people, why must you make this so **difficult**? Are you intentionally trying to waste our time?

Comment: @EthanMcTague:  Have you contacted the site?  At the bottom of the "https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/59858617.html (with your name) it states "Collected from the Internet
Please contact debugcn@gmail.com to delete if infringement.
edited at2021-02-14".

Comment: @jim funny enough that's an entirely different site I hadn't found

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Let’s assume that they’ve properly given you attribution. They are still violating the license if they are saying that you “endorse” their use of your content, as explained by [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#Do_I_need_to_be_aware_of_anything_else_when_providing_attribution.3F):

> ### Do I need to be aware of anything else when providing attribution?
>
> Yes. You need to be careful not to imply any sponsorship, endorsement, or connection with the licensor or attribution party without their permission. Wrongfully implying that a creator, publisher, or anyone else endorses you or your use of a work may be unlawful. Creative Commons makes the obligation not to imply endorsement explicit in its licenses. In addition, if the licensor of a work requests that you remove the identifying credit, you must do so to the extent practical.

This section is called “no endorsement” in the [license text](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode).

Answer (score 7):

Without a link to the offending page it's not possible to formulate an opinion as to whether the site is not honoring their legal requirements.

Posting the link is something you should do before pursuing a takedown notice or other legal action, as there might be potential liability for improperly requesting such a thing.  Additionally, you mentioned that other SO content besides yours has been posted, so other posters may be similarly affected.

Of course, IANAL!

Comment: None of us are lawyers, lol. This legal stuff gets really frustrating but I guess without some of  it the world would be worse with people stealing stuff all over the place.